# Access to http request body raw data

Tags: java, http, servlets, stream, playframework

I am trying to implement a web application using play framework as a replacement for old http server implementation that is interfacing the old non-browser legacy http client.

That client is written in Delphi and it is posting data directly in the body of a request with some header information about it.

I thought I would get something in

```
request.body /* In the play controller */
```

but nothing is there.

See the code below:

```
public static void uploadPicture() {

        InputStream data = request.body;
    String fx = Play.getFile("").getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"uploads"+File.separator+"test.jpg";
        File f = new File(fx);
        FileOutputStream moveTo = new FileOutputStream(fx);
        try {
                byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                for (int x = 0; (data.read(b)) != -1;){
                    moveTo.write(b, 0, x);
            }
        } finally{
            moveTo.close();
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**: 
To clarify my point : I went and I created a simple Dynamic Web Project in eclipse `HttpServlet` and in `doPost()` method when I get the `request.getInputStream()` it contains the file that is sent from the legacy client.

Play is doing something to the body of the request!?

What are my options?

Thanks.

Irfan

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not somewhere else (ie. sloppy implementation in the legacy client)? I use `request.body` and it works as supposed.

Comment: @Samuel Definitely the implementation on the client is very simple it has a filename in header and in the body it is a file.  I went and created a simple Servlet and when I get request.getInputStream() and save that to file, the file is correct. I guess play is doing something to the original request?!

Comment: Ok, it was a bug in Play 1.2.4. I installed latest version 1.2.5 and everything works out of the box. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was a bug in Play 1.2.4. I installed latest version 1.2.5 and everything works out of the box.

You can access raw body of a request in `request.body` in the controller.